# Spring security with Mobile Number and OTP in Java

Tags: java, jhipster

I am using front end angularJs and backend Java.

I have created JWT Token using below code

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        Authentication authentication =   authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        boolean rememberMe = (isRememberMe == null) ? false : isRememberMe;
        String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, rememberMe);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(JWTFilter.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
```

this is working in case of login with username and password

Now I want to do login with mobile and OTP. In that case How I can create the authentication and jwt token ?

Comment: JWT in JHipster is a simple approach, you should rather look at OAuth2 KeyCloak/Okta for more advanced use cases like yours.